# Typescript object property declared as array of custom type silently fails

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am a newbie in Typescript, I am working on a Vue 3 project with Typescript. When I declare the component data, I initialize all the properties with its custom type using the operator `as`. I have a question:

Why in this case I receive an error?

```ts
export interface SectionMenuItem {
  link: string;
  text: string;
}

const menu1: Array<SectionMenuItem> = [
  {
    link2: '/wealth/summary', // Give me error
    text: 'Summary'
  },
  {
    link: '/',
    text: 'Statements'
  },
  {
    link: '/',
    text: 'Transfers'
  },
  {
    link: '/',
    text: 'Report'
  }
];
```

And in this case no error is emited?

```ts
const obj = {
  menu: [
    {
      link2: '/wealth/summary', // No error
      text: 'Summary'
    },
    {
      link: '/',
      text: 'Statements'
    },
    {
      link: '/',
      text: 'Transfers'
    },
    {
      link: '/',
      text: 'Report'
    }
  ] as Array<SectionMenuItem>
};
```

I know I can do this, just curious:

```ts
const menu1: Array<SectionMenuItem> = [
  {
    link2: '/wealth/summary', // Give me error
    text: 'Summary'
  },
  {
    link: '/',
    text: 'Statements'
  },
  {
    link: '/',
    text: 'Transfers'
  },
  {
    link: '/',
    text: 'Report'
  }
];

const obj = {
  menu: menu1
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that using `x as SomeType` does not give you an error is because `x as SomeType` is a **type assertion**.

Basically, what you're telling the compiler is: whatever `x` may look like, I want you to treat it as `SomeType`, and not complain about it.

From the  [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

> *Type assertions* are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast in other
> languages, but it performs no special checking or restructuring of
> data. It has no runtime impact and is used purely by the compiler.
> TypeScript assumes that you, the programmer, have performed any
> special checks that you need.

And from [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion):

> TypeScript's type assertion is purely you telling the compiler that
> you know about the types better than it does, and that it should not second guess you.

Comment: So if I use `as` for initialization data, in that moment it should be empty and when I assign later the value I will get errors. Ok, that make senses.